# Compute line integral for vector function along the curve

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

The question is to compute $\int_{C}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{R}}$ from the origin to (1, 1, 1) along the curve $x=y=z$ and along the curve $y=x^2$, $z=x^3$.

Where $ \vec{F}=(2xyz^3,-x^2z^3-2y,3x^2yz^2$.

I separate the line integral into to parts, the first part is the curve $x=y=z$. The parametric curve would be $ \vec{R_1}=(t,t,t)$ where $ 0\leq t \leq1$.

The second curve is the intersection of the curves $y=x^2$, $z=x^3$. The parameterized curve is $ \vec{R_2}=(t,t^2,t^3)$.

But now, I am stuck on the limits for t for $ \vec{R_2}$.

Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: The range of $t$ for $R_2$ is $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Are you sure you've copied the vector field correctly? (If it were $(2xyz^3, x^2z^3 - 2y, 3x^2yz^2)$, it would be conservative, which would make life much easier).

Comment: Yes, it is the right vector field. Why is this from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' ll do it for the first

we have:

$d\vec{R}=(dx,dy,dz)$

and

$x=y=z$.

so

$dx=dy=dz$

and

$$\vec{F}=(2x^5,-x^5-2x,3x^5)$$.

thus

$\vec{F}.d\vec{R}=$

$(2x^5-x^5-2x+3x^5)dx=$

$(4x^5-2x)dx$.

the integral is

$$\int_0^1(4x^5-2x)dx=$$

$$\frac{2}{3}-1=-\frac{1}{3}$$.

FOR THE SECOND,
you have
$dy=2xdx$ and $dz=3x^2dx$.
i'm sure you could continue.

Comment: Thank you! Why is the limit for the second t goes from 0 to 1? That bugs me a lot...

Comment: it's in the second line of your question. from origin 0 to (1,...

Comment: from the origin to (1, 1, 1)? Do you mean this??

Comment: @Blackgirl5 the  integration  variable is $x$.